# Private route with dynamic URL in react

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, components

I have built a PrivateRoute component in React that takes a given component and renders it if the user is logged in or not.

```
export default function PrivateRoute({component: Component,...rest}) {
return (
    <SessionContext.Consumer > {
        (context) => {

            const {isLoggedIn} = context

            return (
                <Route {...rest}
                render = {
                    props =>
                    isLoggedIn ? ( 
                        <Component {...props} />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to = "/login" / >
                    )
                }
                />
            )
        }
    }
    </SessionContext.Consumer>
);
}
```

Now in App.js I pass my private component like this:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Now the issue is when I want to pass a param in the url. This is how I do for the Route component:

```
<Route path="/user/:user_id" render={(props) =>
              <UserComponent user={props.match.params.user_id} />
            } />
```

This syntax unfortunately doesn't work when using my PrivateRouter.

I've tried several other approaches but I can't find a way to get the user_id in my UserComponent.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your `PrivateRoute` uses prop `component`. But you pass component through `render`. if I understand your question correctly.